# Rainbow-delimiters with hooks

Tags: latex, hooks, tex

It seems that `rainbow-delimiters` does not work with hooks.  For instance I have got

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.sty\\'" . latex-mode))

(require 'rainbow-delimiters)
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook   #'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook #'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
```

Loading an `sty` file does not enable the mode.  I have to do `M-x rainbow-delimiters-mode` on the buffer to take effect.

Comment: How do you check? In my test, it seems to have worked fine but I tested on a light background and had to customize the faces in order to see the colors.

Comment: Seems there is confusion between `tex-mode`, `TeX-mode`, `latex-mode` and `LaTeX-mode`.  So the `latex-mode-hook` did not work because `LaTeX-mode-hook` took over even if `latex-mode` was used in `auto-mode-list`.